# Is it possible to run bash script what find with the find command with other user?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find all bash script in the directories then I'd like to run all of them with another user. In the bash files I'm using a command which are only avaible under the otherUser.

I tried these commands:

```
    sudo -H -u otherUser find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '*myBashFile' -execdir {} \;
    find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name sudo -H -u otherUser '*myBashFile' -execdir {} \;
    sudo -H -u otherUser bash -c 'find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -executable -name '*myBashFile' -execdir {} \;'
```

I always got 'command not found' for my own command in the bash script.

Comment: Does the otherUser have access to your own comand ?

Comment: Yes it does, if i run the script with that user everything is working fine

Comment: how do you become that user? is your own command in the PATH of the otherUser ?

Comment: use the full path to the bash script, in the bash script use the full path to the command

Comment: the "code" in question differs from realiaty to such an extent,  that an answer is probably impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the answers, the PATH thing was the key, this is the final code which is working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=$PATH:/path/of/the/command/
echo otherUserPassword | su -c 'find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -executable -name '*myBashFile' -execdir {} \;' otherUser
```